# What is the best way to add new HTML pages to an existing wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I typically design and build using Bootstrap with a simple text editor. As far as I can see it is not possible to directly add a new HTML page to WP. Is there anyway to integrate bootstrap cleanly to WP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a Custom Template that holds your HTML, then in the WP Backend create a new page and select the desired template. [Here are the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)

This should answer your question on how to add new HTML Pages. "Integrating Bootstrap cleanly" extends to using it in the theme of course.

Answer (score 0):

There is a stater theme [underscores](http://underscores.me/)
first consider using the stater themes, there is a stater theme [__tk](http://themekraft.com/tk-wordpress-bootstrap-starter-theme/)

that is developed by extending **underscores** theme , so you can use this to start developing wordpress+bootstrap site, theme, templates etc.